# How to use Imagemagick to create a text arc?

Tags: php, image, unix, rmagick

My command is:

system(' convert -size 320x100 xc:lightblue -font Courier -pointsize 72 \
           -fill navy -annotate +25+65 \'Ernakulam1\' \
     -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 120 \
           -bordercolor lightblue   font_arcnew.jpg');

This code is not working and is most likely from here:

-virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 120

Please help me!

Comment: Try using double quotes for system(" ... ") call. Remove the new line \ and make it one long command.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - do You have newest ImageMagick installed on Your server?

Answer (score 0):

this question has been here for a bit.

This is the specific question:
mainly this code is not working
-virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 120

My answer: 
-virtual-pixel transparent  -distort Arc 360
the difference is the capital "A" in arc.

This works okay for me.  Thanks to Anthony and ImageMagick.

convert -size 130x130  -font Arial -pointsize 12 -background white  -fill navy label:"Murphy Springs Lodge" -virtual-pixel background  -distort Arc 360 fontCircle.png

Then I use this to view my changes:
open -a Gimp fontCircle.png

[fontCircle.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K4Dm.png)